# how to display image view background color with hash value

Tags: iphone

how to display image view background color with hash values.

i need to place image view background color with #028002.

can any one please help me,

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIColor does not support hex value directly. You need to convert that yourself. Something like this:

```
CGFloat r = (CGFloat)0x02 / 0xFF;
CGFloat g = (CGFloat)0x80 / 0xFF;
CGFloat b = (CGFloat)0x02 / 0xFF;

[UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1.0]
```

Answer (score 5):

I've used next UIColor Category:

```
@implementation UIColor(Tools)

+ (UIColor *)colorWithHex:(NSInteger)hex alpha:(CGFloat)alpha {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((hex & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(hex & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:alpha];
}

@end

// Example of Usage: 
// backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHex:0xe1e1e1 alpha:1.0];
```

There is no need to parse strings here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert hash value to `UIColor` this may help you

http://imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-sdk-convert-hex-color-string-to-uicolor.php

Answer (score 0):

In swift you can use below method

func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {

```
    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    if ((cString.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```